# Calculate probability of consecutive event from R simulations

Tags: r, simulation, probability

The problem is to calculate the PMF of consecutive flips of head (M) in N number of coin flips.
Consecutive heads, k=0, 1, 2,...,N, the PMF is P(M=k).

I use `sample(0:1,N,rep=T,prob=c(0.25,0.75))` to simulate any number of coin flips, but I don't know how to calculate the PMF using R. The ultimate goal is to simulate many large samples of coin flips, then compare PMF of each sample.

Comment: Please explain why this was not posted on CrossValidated.com? This is a statistical question. The code may be the basis for the question but the uncertainty is conceptual rather than syntactic.

Comment: 1. Your code doesn't even run. 2. Your description is ambiguous; there may be several runs of heads - do you mean the longest run? All runs? something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rle` to count lengths of runs

You can use `table` to tabulate the relevant counts within `rle`'s output

You can then scale the output of `table` to produce sample proportions of the occurrence of each run-length.